# I am receiving this error from phpmailer Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed?

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I am working on phpmailer but I am receiving this error, I dont know what is wrong. I search and did many changes. but noting helped me.
I am testing both on live server and on localhost. 
on both I am receiving the error

> Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.
>   https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Please have a look on my code:

```
<?php
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
require("PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php"); // path to the PHPMailer class

$mail = new PHPMailer;

//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';              // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'stockholm85@gmail.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'password';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

$mail->From = 'agohar1985@gmail.com';
$mail->FromName = 'Mailer';
//$mail->addAddress('zia_gt@yahoo.com', 'Zia Ullah');     // Add a recipient
$mail->addAddress('zia_gt@yahoo.com');               // Name is optional

//$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
//$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
?>
```

I have folder on name PHPMailer and mail.php is the file.
I will appreciate your support because I am new to php
Thank you in advance

Comment: This might sound like a radical idea, but have you tried reading the error rmessage and using the link it gives you?

Comment: Yes I did that. I also read the inside documentation also.

Comment: But you're still using an obsolete example and chose not to share the results of all the tests that the guide suggests that might help diagnose your question?

Comment: I am receiving the same error http://itexsis.se/zia/abc/ in this link,, If you click on link the same error is still there. I changed so many scripts but nothing help

Answer (score -2):

open your `cmd` and type the following to get `php-mailer`,

`wget https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/archive/master.zip`

`unzip` the master. mention the `file path`  clearly in your code.

Here

```
<?php
require 'PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php'; //file path

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSMTP(); 
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';    
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'user@gmail.com';
$mail->Password = '_password_';
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';

$mail->From = 'sender@example.com';
$mail->FromName = 'Your Name';
$mail->addAddress('recipient@example.com');

$mail->isHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = 'Test Mail Subject!';
$mail->Body    = 'This is SMTP Email Test';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
 } else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
?>
```

test it

Comment: Hello, I have PHPMailer-master. But I rename it with PHPMailer. I mean the folder

Comment: Hello, Thanks a lot for your support, I download it, past it and the code also but I am getting same error

Comment: where I can search this. I mean extension=php_openssl.dll I am using live server

Comment: run this, `<?php
$inipath = php_ini_loaded_file();

if ($inipath) {
    echo 'Loaded php.ini: ' . $inipath;
} else {
    echo 'A php.ini file is not loaded';
}
?>`

Comment: you will get the place of your php.ini file. and search for the line.& uncomment it.

Comment: yes I am freelancer, I am living in Sweden. Basically I am from Pakistan, Peshawar.

Comment: Here is two files, php.ni-development and php.ni-production /// I am designer and want to get job. php is very important for me to learn. currently i am jobless

Comment: yes it is php.ni, do i nead to remove the -development. here is the file. http://itexsis.se/zia/abc/

Comment: Thank you so much for great support. I mean I am testing it on production live. Then what is the problem. If the problem is in Window, the Widow and my xampp have nothing to do with production live. you are got what I mean?

Comment: This isn't an answer